# What are some of the disadvantages of non-random split for external validation?

Tags: predictive-models, cox-model, validation

Validation procedures on non-random split samples (i.e., when samples are split by centre, region, location) can be considered as external validation. However, what are some of the drawbacks of using non-random split samples?

Can samples also be non-randomly split by "time". For example if I'm running a Cox-regression, would it be feasible to (non-randomly) split the sample by both time and centre so that I get a training data set with N participants from centre x between 2003 and 2005 and a test data set with N' participants from centre y between 2005 and 2007.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first part of your question is answered [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/510551/28500), with links to more detailed reading. Unless you have several hundred events in your set-aside test set, you are better off building a model with all the data and doing internal validation of the model-building process by bootstrap resampling.
Risks include loss of power both in developing and in testing the model, and a failure to model directly the influences of center, region, location, etc.

That latter type of risk gets to the danger in your proposal to split non-randomly by calendar time, presumably by the calendar dates of study entry. One hopes that patient care is improving over time. If you split into cohorts by calendar date of study entry, you lose the ability to evaluate whether that is the case. Keeping the calendar date of study entry as a flexibly modeled predictor instead gets to that issue directly.